# Host (iPage) does not allow remote access. So how can I reach/edit my database?

Tags: php, database, web-hosting, remote-access

I have registered a domain in iPage.com.

But recently i learnt that they are not allowing remote access to database. i am coding my webpage in php5 kohana framework, so when i use `mysql_connect(hostname,username,password)` function in PHP, it returns an error and cannot connect to database. Neither via SQLyog (which i use to access remote databases) i can connect.

What can i do in my codes to create entries into my iPage database? Do i need any additional application or something? I am not sure but i think they dont allow ssh and html tunneling too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved. The problem was that, I was trying to reach my ipage database from my localhost (my own computer), and it was returning error. iPage does not allow remote access, which means that I cannot reach/edit my databases from any database management application (e.g. SQLyog). However, when i created a demo website with a proper index.php trying to reach the database by mysql_connect() function, and uploaded to my domain by cuteFTP, it ran successfully and could reach the database.

Answer (score 5):

You can use HTTP-tunneling in SQLyog

More info: http://faq.webyog.com/21_19_en.html

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: @kleopatra, IGedeon's answer is deceptively acceptable. I see a direct summary, I didn't need to follow the link at all ;)   (Solved my issue with iPage)

Comment: @Jason looks like me being a complete domain noob is glaringly obvious :-) thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try either installing or getting your host to install [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php).  It should help you to deal with databases in your limited setup.

Comment: they have phpmyAdmin already installed actually. but isnt it for manual editing? i mean i should sign in there and edit databases myself by hand. How to add entries to my host database by php code?

Comment: just tagged in case you wont see.sorry im a newbie

Comment: @Shamil If you log into phpMyAdmin, you should be able to create a user and give them privileges on a database.  Then you can use those credentials in your code.